# How to set the default .Net framework version for projects in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How do you set the default framework version for new projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: There is a way to hack it: http://blog.rolpdog.com/2010/04/changing-default-framework-profile-in.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way I know of is the following

1. File -> New Project
2. Select the Framework you want
3. Create the project

From then on the new project dialog will default to the framework you selected in step #2.

Comment: pretty good, but it will set back when I create a project of another version, so it's not really a default setting.

Comment: @Sean, it's a default until you change it ;).  In serious terms though I don't believe there is a way to set the default in a way such that creating a new project won't override it.

Comment: if you're right and there's no way to set and actual default then yours is the right answer.  Will wait a few hours just in case someone trumps you on that though. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a very old question but I needed the answer to it several times now and I keep searching for it. So, I will share my experience here and hopefully in the future I would not need to search for it too long and those who are looking for the same can find it too. I just tested it with Visual Studio 2015. Open the registry hive **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\NewProjectDialog** and look for the value **FxVersion** (REG_SZ type). For me it used to be 4.6.1 and I changed it to 4.6.2. Now when I create a new projects they target .NET v.4.6.2 by default.