# Changing the Default Target Framework Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to change the default target framework that projects point to when they are created?  I want to target the 4.0. framework by default and NOT the Client Profile version of the 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 (and older versions) will remember the last target framework you chose when using `File -> New -> New Project`.  So if you create a new project using 4.0, the next time you create a new project 4.0 will be preselected as the target framework.

**EDIT : Further to comment below:**

Having looked at this a little more there is another solution that is slightly less faffy than the info on the link I posted in the comments below.

Create a new solution/project with the setup you need, then goto `File -> Export Template`. After you have done there you can then use your new template when you go `File -> New -> New Project`.

Seems to work, not thoroughly tested it though.

Comment: The problem is that it keeps choosing the "4.0 Client Framework" instead of the full-fledged 4.0 framework.  Even when I select .NET Framework 4.0 when creating a new project.

Comment: That is odd, just tried it here and got the same issue - I created a new console application project as .NET 4 but on checking the properties for the project it was .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  A little googling found this solution, but it is a faff: http://blog.rolpdog.com/2010/04/changing-default-framework-profile-in.html

Comment: I never even once realized there was a drop down for that in the project create dialog.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to change it by hacking the template:

http://blog.rolpdog.com/2010/04/changing-default-framework-profile-in.html

Which is probably close to the same as MrEyes answer.

Answer (score 6):

I know the question was originally for VS2010, but in Visual Studio 2015, it's much easier to change the target framework by default.

When adding a new project, change the framework at the top -

[image: Select framework when adding a project]

When you come to add another project, I've found that VS remembers the last selection I made.

Answer (score 1):

In my VS 2010, I right-click on the project, select Properties, select the Compile tab, scroll down to the Advanced Compile Options button and click on it.  The Advanced Compile Settings window appears.  The last drop-down in that window is a list for target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how [you do it with VS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It appears to be a similar (the same?) process for VS2010. (I just did it in my own VS2010 development environment.)

- Right click on the name of the project.
- Click the Application tab.
- In the 'Target Framework' list, select the framework that you wish to use. It will differ depending on which .NET frameworks you have available on your system.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't want to have to manually change this each time I create a new project.

Comment: @Achilles - Ah. Well...based on this question (which seems to be the same as your own), it's not really possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927909/how-to-set-the-default-net-framework-version-for-projects-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

Its as easy as in your Visual studio.

1. Go to the 4th menu option on top, 'website'.
2. Under websites go to option, 'start options'.
3. Under start options, go to 'build' option.
4. Change the target framework there to what so ever framework.