# Microsoft.Web.Administration (for IIS7 automation) doesn't work in VS 2010

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm trying to experiment with Microsoft.Web.Administration on my Windows 7 x64 box, using Visual Studio 2010.  When I add the DLL to references in my C# project, I can see its namespaces and classes pop up in Intellisense.

But as soon as I build, I get "The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)", and I get build errors in the code I've written, as if the DLLs aren't even there.

There are two sets of IIS7 DLLs that I can see, in:

- %windir%\system32\inetsrv
- %windir%\syswow64\inetsrv

But both sets seem to do the same thing: Apparently initially work, then fail on build.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is a .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0 project, open the project properties. On the Application tab it will have probably defaulted to either of:

- .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile
- .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Change this to .NET Framework 3.5 or .NET Framework 4. Your project should then build just fine.

As the compiler error points out, `Microsoft.Web.Administration` has a dependency on `System.Web` which isn't referenced in the 3.5/4.0 client profiles.

Comment: You're exactly right.  Thanks!  That Client-Profile-by-default setting causes me no end of trouble.  Is there a way to turn it off, and have WinForms projects default to using the full .NET 4.0 instead?

Comment: @kyralessa - looks like you can't. This was raised on MS connect and closed as By Design: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524786. I found this on SO though that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595212/changing-the-default-target-framework-visual-studio-2010/4595329#4595329

Comment: @kyralessa - just in case you missed this in the comments in that answer: http://blog.rolpdog.com/2010/04/changing-default-framework-profile-in.html

Comment: It's interesting to note that as of .NET 4.5, [the "Client Profile" has been dumped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx), so this problem won't occur anymore.

Comment: @Kyralessa - good move. Every time I knock out a quick console app to test something that sodding client profile trips me up :)