# Create a class library that targets asp.net 4.5 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Forgive if I am being incredibly dim, but how can I create a class library in Visual Studio that targets asp.net 4.5? As it stands, every time I add a new class library it defaults to DNX 1.0.0-beta5, which I don't want to use

For illustration purposes:
I create the initial MVC project targeting 4.5, which works absolutely fine
[image]

I then add a class library, again targeting 4.5
[image]

I then go look at it, and it's using .net 5 beta 5/DNX
[image]

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot?  Is the problem that you don't like the default, or that you completely unable to target asp.net.  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4595212/270155

Comment: @AndyJoiner I've added some screenshots. The problem is I'm unable to target 4.5, it's forcing me to use .net 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the top level of C# templates instead of C#/Node, you will see three different Class Library templates: "Class Library (Package)", "Class Library (Portable)", and just plain "Class Library."  Choose "Class Library."

The Class Library (Package) template is intended for creating Nuget Packages.  I will pass along the feedback that this is causing confusion.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much